# Getters and setters using Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an Entity i.e `Users`. I want to make getters and setters of this entity in Doctrine, so that Doctrine can read it.

How can I do it, can someone provide me basic example? I am a beginner

How to insert data in this database table?

Here is my **Users entity**

```
<?php
 /**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 * Total Number of Columns : 32
 */
class Users{

/* Attributes of Users */

     /** 
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer") 
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @dummy
     * @Assert\NotEmpty
     */
       private $id;

     /** 
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotEmpty
     */
       private $name;


     /** 
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotEmpty
     */
       private $email;

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to look into the documentation?

Answer (score 7):

Try with this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle:YourEntity
```

Comment: But first I have to define getters and setters . How to do that ?

Comment: If you use this command, doctrine generates getters and setters automatically for your entity.

Comment: This would be the only correct answer, because no need to create the getters and setters yourself, this command does it for you!

Comment: There are various instances where the generators don't work - especially if you're not storing your entities in the default place. So, while this is likely to work for the OP, it's actually not the 'correct' answer. Relying on generators is a bad idea until you know what's happening under the hood and how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you wanted to have a setter for your `email` property, you would do:

```php
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

The first is the setter (it sets the value of `email` on the object) and the second is the getter (it gets the value of `email` from the object). Hope that helps :)

Comment: Is this using Doctrine ? Cz i guess doctrine use __set() and __get() functions

Comment: You don't write your accessors with Doctrine - they're just normal PHP objects, and Doctrine uses the normal, generic accessors to access the properties of your object.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to perform insertion ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html will help you out as much as is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use magic methods if you're lazy enough not to define your own methods for each property.

```
    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }
    public function __set($property,$value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
```

It's better to create a method for each property though

```
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

Have a look at the answers here [Doctrine 2 Whats the Recommended Way to Access Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461296/doctrine-2-whats-the-recommended-way-to-access-properties)

Comment: But how can i insert data using form ?