# doctrine2 association is not initialized

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a Class like the following:

```
/** @Entity **/
class orgGroup{

    //id and stuff...

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     **/
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="orgGroupType", inversedBy="_orgGroups")
     * @JoinColumn(name="_orgGroupType")
     **/

    private $_orgGroupType;

    //...
}
```

But when i load this Object from my database via

```
$groups = $em->getRepository("orgGroup")->findAll();
```

I just get the name correctly but not the _orgGroupType... and i dont know why... OrgGroup is the owner of orgGroupType and its just ONE object and not an array. My Webservice always just says:

```
{"error":[],"warning":[],"message":[],"data":[{"name":"AdministratorGroup","description":null,"_orgGroupType":{"__ isInitialized __":false}}]}
```

The result is:

```
"name":"AdministratorGroup",
"description":null,
"_orgGroupType":{"__ isInitialized __":false}
```

but should be:

```
"name":"AdministratorGroup",
"description":"some description",
"_orgGroupType":{name:"test"}
```

So there are **2** errors... and I have no idea why.
All the data is set correctly in the database.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:
Here's the missing code of my orgGroupType -entity

```
/** @Entity **/
class orgGroupType {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="orgGroup", mappedBy="_orgGroupType")
     **/
    private $_orgGroups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_orgGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just call json_encode on your entity?

Comment: Yeah something like json_encode. that was the first problem. But the other problem with the "unset" description property is still unsolved...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, try to watch what happening in code with xdebug

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This looks to me like a lazy-loading-issue. How do you get the data from the object into the Webservice answer?

Doctrine2 is lazy-loading if you don't configure something else, that means your `$groups = $em->getRepository("orgGroup")->findAll();` won't return real `orgGroup` objects, but Proxy objects ([Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-lazy-loading)).

That means a `$group` object won't have it's description or orgGroupType value until you call `$group->getDescription()` or `$group->getOrgGroupType()` (then Doctrine loads them automatically), so you need to do that before writing the data into the JSON-response for the webservice. It won't work if you somehow loop through the object properties without using the getter methods.

I hope that was the problem :)

Comment: But whats the difference between accessing the property or calling a self-written getter method?

Comment: The Proxy classes inherit from your Entity classes and override your Getters - if you call them, they call a `_load` method or something like that and read the data you want from the database. If you just call `object->property`, there is no point where the Proxy class could initiate lazy-load. Here is a question with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090609/how-can-public-fields-break-lazy-loading-in-doctrine-2

Comment: @Manuel? How to did you solve the problem? There's also a problem regarding DoctrineCollection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971637/count-records-in-related-entity/31988152#31988152

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I use Symfony since 3 years now and I didn't understand why sometimes my associations were empty... use the "get" function in Twig solved my problem. For example, instead of `{{ product.type.name }}` I wrote `{{ product.getType.name }}`

Answer (score 34):

Try to change fetch mode to **EAGER**.
with PHP annotation :

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="****", fetch="EAGER").
```

or with [PHP attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php) (PHP >= v8) :

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(fetch: 'EAGER')]
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This is a bad idea if there is a lot of entities on the other side and you don't necessarily need them. They'll be loaded for no reason.

Comment: I agree with @BenoitDuffez, if it seems solve issue, it could be that associations are required (in Entity files) `#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]` and this criteria is not true in db.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Group.php ...

public function addUser(User $user): self
{
    if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users[] = $user;
        $user->addJoinedGroup($this);     /** VERY IMPORTANT **/
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Same in `User.php`
Without it, it didn't do anything in my database

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to initialize the orgGroups collection in the orgGroupType  entity

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="orgGroup", mappedBy="_orgGroupType")
 */
protected $orgGroups ;

public function __construct() {
    $this->orgGroups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

You might need to include the following in the Entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection,
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesnt solve my problem :(. I forgot to post the code of the orgGroupType-Class, but its implemented like you posted. I appended the missing code to my first post.

Do you have any other ideas :-)?

Comment: __construct won't be called when you retrieve object from database

Comment: Okay.
One problem was, that my WebService function didnt packed the data correctly into my json-object. When I don't access the orgGroupType Object, it doesn't get initialized. But after i accessed it one time, i can easily pack it in...

But the other problem with the description property is still unsolved. Its just a string and I just get "null" from the entityManager.

In the Database my Object looks like:
id: 1
name: AdministratorGroup
description: some description
_orgGroupType: 1

But the entityManager gives me:
id: 1
name: AdministratorGroup
description: null
_orgGroupType: 1