# Symfony - Doctrine relationship - Returns relational model with null values

Tags: php, symfony

First things first. I am totally new on Symfony, and I am trying to solve an issue but I don't know how. So, if my questions seem to weird to you, then please help me by explaining where I am wrong and thank you in advance.

So, in my DB I have the following tables:

`payments`, with columns: `id`, `merchant_sevice_id`, `customer_id`, `status`, `type`, `created_at`, `amount_amount`, `amount_currency`. `payment_method_payment_method_type`, `payment_method_payment_method_id`, `vat` and `failed_reason`.

and

`merchant_services` with columns: `id`, `payment_institution_id`, `account_id`, `name`, `capacity`, `capabilities`, `created_at`, `mid`, `status`, and `blocked_bins_id`.

The two tables are connected with a `manyToOne` relationship. So, many payments could belong to one `Merchant`

Now, the problem is when I try to get one `Payment` and check the relationship with `Merchants`. The fields of the `Merchant` are all `nulled`, while in DB I have values.

So a given record in `payments` table looks like that:

```
| id                                   | merchant_service_id                  | customer_id                          | status | type | created_at           | amount_amount | amount_currency | payment_method_payment_method_type | payment_method_payment_method_id     | vat | failed_reason |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0fede82a-b898-4287-83e3-8f7d28d576db | 548d36d9-f1e6-4854-b513-1559b2499b45 | 237369c4-feed-4e24-964a-638938c7940c | failed | SALE |  2018-06-15 07:36:28 | 100           | GBP             | card                               | f35f78c4-2da7-432a-ace5-c0829db448af | 5   |               |
```

And the related record in merchants is like that:

```
| id                                   | payment_institution_id               | account_id                           | name | capacity | capabilities | created_at          | mid | status | blocked_bins_id                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 548d36d9-f1e6-4854-b513-1559b2499b45 | c7a02b53-6c8b-4aa9-b1af-1c5b4978d844 | 4d239c0f-1fa0-4d70-88b4-95b6f05e7bf5 | Test | 0        | ["AUTH"]     | 2018-06-06 06:36:15 | 53  | active | e3d6a222-68cd-468c-a78a-b0da8ff0caf9 |
```

Then, the output of my query in the DB seems like that:

[image]

As you could see, the values of the `merchantService` are all null *(except the ID)*.

So the question is, what it could make this problem? Could be a serializer? Is that a kind of Symfony issue? Actually I am looking for a hint on where to look for solution of that issue.

Again sorry if my question is too weired, but I am really blocked and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Doctrine relationships are lazy-loaded (unless you specify otherwise). I suspect what you're looking at there is a proxy object - you should still be able to use any getter methods to actually fetch the properties, at which point it'll go back to the database and fetch the full object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doctrine2 association is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431614/doctrine2-association-is-not-initialized)

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that Payment::setMerchant($merchant) is never being called.  Doctrine allows you to map relationships but it's up to you to actually set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As iainn indicated in his comment Doctrine relationships are by default lazy-loaded (you can change that by using `fetch="EAGER"` in the ManyToOne annotation). Indeed, you can easily observe that in your screenshot, as the merchantService object has property `__isInitialized__` set to false. That means it is a proxy object of MerchantService class.

[image]

Comment: Wow !! :) You send me so detailed answer. Thank you very much iiirxs :)