# Doctrine 2 Hydrator - fields with underline

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I working with zf2.1.3 and doctrine 2. I was trying to hydrate information on my class and realize that the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` doesn't work with fields that have underline on it, like `cat_id`.

Here an example:

```
/* namespace Application\Entity; */

class Foo
{
    private $cat_id;
    private $cat_name;

    public function getCatId()
    {
        return $this->cat_id;
    }

    public function setCatName($name)
    {
        $this->cat_name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCatName()
    {
        return $this->cat_nome;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}

/* namespace Application\Controller; */

use \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;
public function indexAction()
{
    $hydrator = new DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager(), 'Application\Entity\Foo');
    $foo = $hydrator->hydrate(array('cat_name' => 'Frank Moraes'), new Foo());
    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($foo, 'Foo Hydrator');

    $hydrator = new DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager(), 'Application\Entity\Bar');
    $bar = $hydrator->hydrate(array('name' => 'Frank Moraes'), new Bar());
    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($inscrit, 'Bar Hydrator');
}
```

This code returns the following:

```
Foo Hydrator
object(Application\Entity\Foo)
    private 'cat_id' => null
    private 'cat_name' => null

Bar Hydrator
object(Application\Entity\Foo)
    private 'id' => null
    private 'name' => 'Frank Moraes'
```

So my question is: Why Doctrine Hydrator doesn't work with fields that have underline in it?
How can I make this work?

Thank you!

**Edited**

Sorry for the long time with no answer. A have no access to SO on my work!

I tried the following:

```
$hydrator = new DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager(), 'Application\Entity\Foo', false);
```

For the example I posted here, this `false` parameter works fine.

But, it didn't work when I'm binding the class on a form!

Someone have a clue?

Comment: I'd post this question on the Doctrine Users Google group.

Comment: That's because the default inflector doesn't handle underscores. You need to tweak it on your own or post an issue on the issue tracker of doctrine module at https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues

I can tell you right now that I don't have time to look into it right now though.

Comment: I posted the issue on https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/190

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several months after this has been asked, but I've been checking the source code of the `DoctrineObject` hydrator just now, and I think this is what's going on:

By default, unless you construct the `DoctrineObject` hydrator with the `byValue` flag as `false`, the hydrator will work in `byValue` mode. What that means is that it tries to construct getter and setter method names from the values that you're trying to hydrate, and the way it does that is by calling `ucfirst` on the field name and prepending get/set to that.

So, for instance, you have `cat_name`, so it will try the getter method `getCat_name` which clearly is incorrect.

You have 4 choices, then:

- **A:** `camelCase` your variable names
- **B:** Set `byValue` to false (so that it tries to access the variables directly) [although I think you might have to make the variables public in that case... I'm not sure how visibility will affect it, as I haven't tried it before]
- **C:** Use a different hydration `Strategy` or
- **D:** Just have weird getter and setter names like `getCat_name` (please don't do this).

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I'd solved this by changing my variable names to camelCase. Good to know the reason of this problem!

Comment: For option **B** you shouldn't set the properties to public because it will [break lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090609/how-can-public-fields-break-lazy-loading-in-doctrine-2). If you want access to your properties without getters and setters you should implement [magic `__get` and `__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: for option **B** protected and private properties will be filled, it uses reflection and ignores access methods (getters and setters) and access modifiers (protected and private)

Comment: Thank you.  Using a Framework like ZF2 where the ClassMethods hydrator works differently, this sent me for a 30 minute loop.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty...

```
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
        while ($pos = strrpos($key,'_')) {                                  
            $key = substr_replace($key, '', $pos, 1);
            $capitalized = strtoupper($key[$pos]);
            $key[$pos] = $capitalized;                                
        }
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use this trick:

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="column_name", type="string") */
protected $columnName;

function get(...);
function set($columnName){$this->columnName = $columnName}
```

Hope helps