# Entity-class mapping invalid: inconsistent with each other

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a table "cms_objects" // Object.php - that stores all object info
I have another table "cms_media" // Media.php - that stores all media info

An object can have many media items (post with lots of different images)

In Object.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="Object")
 */
private $cms_media;
```

In Media.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Object", inversedBy="cms_media")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @Annotation\Exclude()
 */
private $object;
```

When I run: `php public/index.php orm:validate-schema` - I get:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Application\Entity\Cms\Media' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings Application\Entity\Cms\Media#object and Application\Entity\Cms\Object#cms_media are inconsistent with each other.


[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Application\Entity\Cms\Object' mapping is invalid:
* The association Application\Entity\Cms\Object#cms_media refers to the owning side field Application\Entity\Cms\Media#Object which does not exist.
```

Ideally, I need to be able to create a ZF2 form with element: 'media' or 'cms_media' but I haven't been able to validate it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [FQCN](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Fully_Qualified-Class-Name-(Java)-(FQCN).html) inside the annotations. Instead of

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="Object")
 */
```

try

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Cms\Media", mappedBy="Object")
 */
```

in both entities.

Also i would like to recommend using **camelCased** entity properties instead of **underscored_ones**. Hydration process of the entities with underscored properties using DoctrineObject hydrator is problematic. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329871/doctrine-2-hydrator-fields-with-underline).

**BEWARE** - Using unnecessary bi-directional associations increases your object graph and domain model complexity. [Best practice](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html) is avoiding bi-directional associations if possible.

For this case, you can rewrite the same mapping using uni-directional relation between `Post` (Object) and `Media` entities if you don't need reverse access from **Media** to **Post** like

`$media->getPost()`

For example `Application/Entity/Cms/Post.php` :

```
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Post
{  
    /**
     * One to many, unidirectional
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Cms\Media")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_to_media",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id",unique=true)
     *      })
     **/
    private $media;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->media = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and `Application/Entity/Cms/Media.php` :

```
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Media
{
    // No need to know about post
}
```

Comment: This worked right away for me :) Now just to update Services/Controllers/Views... and yeah I don't need to know about the 'post' from media so it's nice to have it like what you suggested, thanks!

Comment: I get:

A new entity was found through the relationship 'Application\Entity\Cms\Object#media' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Application\Entity\Cms\Media@0000000030c7f5dc000000003546e9e1. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Application\Entity\Cms\Media#__toString()' to get a clue.

How would I add Media?

Comment: NVM, I got it working, had to just persist the $media = new Media(); object